# Proof of indefinite integral of inverse function

Tags: calculus, integration

> Assume that $f$ has a inverse on its domain.
>
> a. Let $y = f^{-1}(x)$ and show that
>       $\int f^{-1}(x)dx=\int yf'(y)dy$
>
> b. Use part a to show that
>
> $\int f^{-1}(x)dx= yf(y)-\int yf(y)dy$
>
> c. Use part b to evaluate $\int ln(x)dx$
>
> d. Use part b to evaluate $\int sin^{-1}(x)dx$
>
> e. Use part b to evaluate $\int tan^{-1}(x)dx$

Parts c through e (and perhaps even b) seem fairly straightforward, but I'm stumped on how to prove a. I have a feeling I'm to use integration by parts, but every time I try I hit a dead end.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f^{-1}(x)=y \implies f(y)=x$. Differentiating both sides of $f(y)=x$ gives $ f'(y) \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}=1 \implies f'(y) dy=dx$ Now just substitute.

Comment: I do not see how that answers any part of the question. Please clarify which part of the question this relates to and how it helps.

Comment: I thought this was homework assignment. I would rather give part of the answer than the full answer. Also he said he was stumped on a. So this is about a.

Comment: Also if I differentiate the thingy I asked him to differentiate then that would be the full answer basically to a) besides the substitution part. @Rory Daulton are you suggesting I give him the full answer?

Comment: @randomgirl I second what Rory Daulton asked. The differentiation of both sides of f(y) = x is f'(y) = 1, to my knowledge. How do I use that to formulate the proof? I don't want the "full answer," just a bit more clarity.

Comment: I differentiated both sides (using chain rule for the left hand side) for you... Can you try doing the substitution ?

Comment: @randomgirl: I did not mean you should give the complete answer. I like that you gave a hint. But the OP did state that he did some work, and I really did not see where your hint was leading. I think your current answer is much better: more clear, and still not giving a complete answer. +1 for you now!

Comment: @randomgirl I figured it out now, thank you!

Comment: perfect @FeynmansBongos